# BackEnd Recalculate MongoID on reciving it from Front?

Tags: spring, database, mongodb, vue.js, persistence

Good Evening.
I'm facing an issue concerning mongoDB and front end logic.
The flow is pretty simple and it should be straight.
I'm using Spring whit reposistory pattern, + mongoDb for back end logic, and VueJs3.0 for front end.
I'm using two model right now

```
@Document("Table")//CollecionTame
public class Table {
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private ObjectId id;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String nameId;
    private boolean closed;
    private String extraInfo;
    @Nullable
    private List<Order> associatedOrder;
    private String waiter;
    public Table() {
    }
```

and

```
@Document("Orders")//CollecionTame
public class Order {
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    ObjectId id;
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String itemName;
    private String extraInfo;
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String printedString;
    private String waiter;
    private boolean paid;
```

(omitted getter\setter\costructors)

now when frontend ask for Table item, the back will send a json, this is an example

```
 {
        "id": {
            "timestamp": 1683544850,
            "date": "2023-05-08T11:20:50.000+00:00"
        },
        "nameId": "Tavolo 1",
        "closed": false,
        "extraInfo": "fabio",
        "associatedOrder": [
            {
                "id": {
                    "timestamp": 1683544873,
                    "date": "2023-05-08T11:21:13.000+00:00"
                },
                "itemName": "Architetto",
                "extraInfo": "",
                "printedString": "TBD",
                "waiter": "TBD",
                "paid": true
            },
            {
                "id": {
                    "timestamp": 1683544981,
                    "date": "2023-05-08T11:23:01.000+00:00"
                },
                "itemName": "Kozel",
                "extraInfo": "",
                "printedString": "TBD",
                "waiter": "TBD",
                "paid": false
            }
        ],
        "waiter": "SYSADMIN"
    }
```

asyou can see, the ObjectId is parsed in an object whit timestamp and date (i think few parameters is missing.
Frontend did not touch in any way the outer nor the inner id

```
template lang="html">
  
<div class="outer">
<Card class="card-component">
  <template #header>
  </template>
  <template #title> Ordine </template>
  <template #content class="inner">
<div class="inner">
  <DataTable :value="currentOrderInner"  :columnClasses='text-right' tableStyle="min-width: 5rem" @row-click="">
  <Column field="itemName" header="Nome"></Column>
  <Column field="extraInfo" header="extraInfo"></Column>
  <Column header="Salda Oggetto">
    <template #body="currentOrderInner">
      <Button :icon="currentOrderInner.data.paid===true ?  'pi pi-check':'pi pi-times'" :severity="currentOrderInner.data.paid===true ? 'primary':'danger'" text rounded aria-label="Filter" v-model="currentOrderInner.associatedOrder" :binary="true" @click="test('cc')" />
      <Checkbox v-model="currentOrderInner.data.paid" :binary="true" />
    </template>
  </Column>
</DataTable>
<br>
        <Button icon="pi pi-check" label="Save" @click="save()" />
</div>
  </template>
</Card>
</div>


</template>

<script lang="js">
import axios from 'axios';
import {reactive, toRaw,computed} from 'vue';
  export default  {
    name: 'salda-ordini',
    props: {currentOrderInner:{type:Array,require:true},currentTableInner:{type:String,require:true}},
    mounted () {

    },
    data () {
      return {
       
      }
    },
    methods: {
test(x){
console.log(x)
}
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods:{
      test(){
        console.log(this.currentOrderInner)
      },
      save(){
        console.log(this.currentTableInner)
        console.log(this.currentOrderInner.id)
        this.currentOrderInner.forEach(element => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/order/'+this.currentTableInner;
        const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', // non serve mi sà eh
        'user': 'SYSADMIN'
      };
      const data = element //ciclo occhio
      console.log("invio richiesta");
      console.log(toRaw(data));
      axios.put(url,data,{headers})
        });
       

      }
    }
}


</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .salda-ordini {

  }
</style>
```

as you can see, this is the VueJs Component who work whit the inner object and do not perform any logic aside changing the currentOrderInner.data.paid value (false\true).

So the Id should be the very same, but when i debug the backend i notice the parsed ObjectId does have another Id.
Funny thing is both Objects Id (the one send BY the backend, and one parsed by Backend) have the very same timestamp and date, but different outcome.
Debug show me additional params such as counter and randomvalue 1 and 2.

Question is: i overlook some passage? did i must avoid to send mongoId as object and i need to pass it as simple string whit a DTO and parse it every time?